# Enlaces en imágenes no funcionan y me desmontan la galería grid

Tags: html5, css, grid

Estoy usando este bonito `grid` de imágenes: **Visitad el enlace porque ahí es donde está todo el código que uso, además podréis trabajar el código si fuere necesario allí mismo:**  (http://jsfiddle.net/edlea/uZv3n/) para mostrar unos logotipos en una web.
Cuando le pongo los enlaces que corresponden a las url de cada logotipo, me hace un salto de línea situándome el logotipo donde inserto la imagen encima y todos los demás debajo, en vez de conservar el `grid` establecido y encima no me agrega el enlace, no sé que hago mal.
Y tengo que ponerle los enlaces sí o sí.
Yo lo pongo así:

```html
<a href="http://miweb.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/69D2E7/ffffff"></a>
```

Comment: Puedes añadir un ejemplo completo de tu codigo? Porque con un a, poco te vamos a poder decir

Comment: el código está en jsfiddle por eso no lo he copiado..

Comment: Creo que es un problema con el css al añadir la imagen dentro de a, puedes indicar el codigo wur tienes tu? porque en jsfiddle no tiene la imagen dentro de a. Indica el css también

Comment: Yo he copiado el código de jsfiddle sin alterarlo. Habria que conseguir que funcione en jsfiddle y entonces lo podría en mi web igual como me digas

Comment: prueba de añadir el tag `style="display: inline;` en cada `img`

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo completo de como lo pondrías, por favor?

Comment: `<img style="display: inline;" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/69D2E7/ffffff">`

Comment: Publicalo como respuesta que es la buena, Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir que los distintos `img` esten en la misma línea existe el `style` precisamente llamado `inline`.

Para utilziarlo en cualquier `img` es tan fácil cómo usar el tag `style="display: inline;"`, en tu caso concreto:

```
<img style="display: inline;" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/69D2E7/ffffff">
```

Para cada uno de los `img` que quieras que ocupen la misma línea (siempre que haya espacio suficiente)

Comment: @aldanux si no me equivoco por defecto son `inline-block` --> su comportamiento es muchas veces igual que el `inline` pero según las medidas de la imagen no es siempre así.

Comment: Si miras su fiddle verás que tiene definido por defecto `inline-block` --> por eso me he imagindo que haciendo override de eso se solucionaría (y por extraño que sea así ha sido). Depende también del navegador que se esté usando; en la mayoría YA tendría que funcionar, en eso tienes razón.